# Parsing a string with quotes in GETOPTS

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to accept a space delimited string in place of $OPTARG while parsing an option

For example

```
./script -k '1 2 ad'ias'
```

As seen the third string can contain any special character. Is there a way that I can overlook the quote in between as I want to parse the entire string and process some options

Tried inserting the \ character but that does not work for my case because I cannot insert any character in my string.

```
while getopts "a:k:" option
do
   echo "${option}"
   case ${option} in
     a)
        function_a ${OPTARG}   # <-- no quotes
      ;;
     k)
        function_k "${OPTARG}" # <-- quotes
      ;;
   esac
done
```

Comment: The command you use to run your script must be valid shell syntax; the example you give is *not* valid shell syntax (improper quoting), and there's nothing your script can do to change this. If you're trying to pass a single-quote as part of an argument to the script, there are a number of available quoting methods: you could use `./script -k "1 2 ad'ias"` or `./script -k 1\ 2\ ad\'ias` or `./script -k '1 2 ad'"'"'ias'` or `./script -k $'1 2 ad\'ias'` or... Anyway, once your script gets the argument, all it really needs to do it put double-quotes around it when using it (e.g. `"${OPTARG}"`).

Comment: Yeah but my problem is my input can be values with all special characters. Which is why I turned up here to see if there are other ideas that can be discussed

Comment: I'm not clear on where you're running into trouble with this. Is it in constructing a command that'll pass special characters to the script in its arguments, or in how the script handles them once it receives the arguments? BTW, there is one character you cannot pass in an argument: the ASCII NUL (hex 00).

Comment: Oh I am running into trouble with sending multiple arguments with space. Say I am sending keys which might have all the above characters. Then handling them as strings is a bit impossible

Comment: I might just want to send it like ./script -a 12 34 kla#42@!' 2 M rtqas;::#

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I fully understand what the difficulty is; handling strings with special characters is a bit tricky, but (except the NUL character) basically doable. The main things to watch out for are:

- When you represent a string literal (in a script, or when passing arguments to a script), you must use a valid shell *representation* of that string, not just the raw string. For example, suppose you want to pass/use this string:

  ```
  12 34 kla#42@!' 2 M$" rtqas;::#
  ```

  There are a number of ways of *representing* this string for use in a shell script or command line. You can leave it unquoted but escape the individual special characters, like this:

  ```
  12\ 34\ kla\#42@\!\'\ 2\ M\$\"\ rtqas\;::\#
  ```

  Or you could wrap it in double-quotes, and escape just those characters that retain special meaning inside double-quotes (that is, double-quotes, backquotes, and dollar signs, and if it's a bash interactive shell exclamation marks):

  ```
  "12 34 kla#42@!' 2 M\$\" rtqas;::#"    # For a non-interactive shell
  "12 34 kla#42@\!' 2 M\$\" rtqas;::#"   # For an interactive shell
  ```

  If it didn't contain single-quotes, you could single-quote it; since it does, you can't use that method. But you can mix methods, e.g. using single-quotes around the parts that don't contain single-quotes and escaping or double-quoting the single quote:

  ```
  '12 34 kla#42@!'\'' 2 M$" rtqas;::#'    # Single-quote is escaped
  '12 34 kla#42@!'"'"' 2 M$" rtqas;::#'   # Single-quote is double-quoted
  ```

  In bash (but not some other shells), there's also ANSI-C-escaped strings, written with `$' ... '`:

  ```
  $'12 34 kla#42@!\' 2 M$" rtqas;::#'    # Single-quote is the only character that needs escaping
  ```

  Note that all of the above are just different ways of representing the exact same string; once the shell parses it, it comes out the same from any of them. You can use whatever's convenient, but you *must* use a syntactically valid representation of the string.
- Once the string is stored in a parameter/variable, you must put double-quotes around references to that variable. In most shell contexts, when a variable is used without quotes, the shell will split it into words (based on spaces or whatever's in `IFS`), and try to expand anything that looks like a file wildcard; you don't want this. But if it's in double-quotes, the variable gets expanded and *no further parsing is done*, it's just passed through unmolested.

  Actually, you should almost always double-quote variable references in shell scripts even if you don't expect them to contain special characters. We see so many shell questions here that have the answer "if you double-quoted your variable references, you wouldn't have this problem"...

Here's an example, based on your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

printopt() {
   printf '%s value is: <<%s>>\n' "$1" "$2"    # Double-quotes required here
}

while getopts "a:k:" option
do
   case "${option}" in    # This is one of the few places it's safe to leave off double-quotes. But they don't hurt.
     a)
        printopt "-a" "${OPTARG}"    # Double-quotes required here
      ;;
     k)
        printopt "-k" "${OPTARG}"    # Double-quotes required here
      ;;
   esac
done
```

And running it with various representations of strings:

```
$ ./argtest.sh -a 12\ 34\ kla\#42@\!\'\ 2\ M\$\"\ rtqas\;::\# -k "1 2 ad'ias"
-a value is: <<12 34 kla#42@!' 2 M$" rtqas;::#>>
-k value is: <<1 2 ad'ias>>
$ ./argtest.sh -a '12 34 kla#42@!'"'"' 2 M$" rtqas;::#' -k $'1 2 ad\'ias'
-a value is: <<12 34 kla#42@!' 2 M$" rtqas;::#>>
-k value is: <<1 2 ad'ias>>
```

Ok, ok, there are a few situations where it's more complicated than that:

- There are some situations where a string will be run through the shell parsing process multiple times, such as when it's being run over `ssh` (the command gets processed by the local shell, passed to the remote computer, then processed by *that* shell and executed), or used as a shell `alias` (the `alias` command gets parsed, result stored, then parsed again when you use it). In these cases, you essentially need two (or possibly more) *layers* of quoting/escaping: take the raw string, quote/escape by any of the above methods, then take *that* string and quote/escape *that* (probably by a different method).
- Some versions of `echo` will parse escape (backslash) sequences in the string (using different rules than the shell itself does), which can cause confusion. I recommend using `printf` instead when this might be an issue; the only problem is that it's more complex than `echo`: it doesn't just print its arguments, it uses the first argument is a format string which controls how the rest of the arguments are printed. See my examples in the script above.
- If you are passing the string to another script that doesn't use double-quotes around its parameter & variable references, you are doomed. In this case, the only thing that can be done is to fix that other script.